# Counting order preserving maps

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $P$ is finite poset and $\langle n\rangle$ a chain of $n$ elements. We can show that the number of order-preserving maps is given by (can provide details if necessary);

$$\Omega(P;n)=\sum_{s=1}^{|P|}e_s{n\choose s}$$

Where $e_s$ is the number of surjective poset maps from $P$ onto $\langle s\rangle$.

I'm now asked to show that the number of strict order preserving maps from $P \rightarrow \langle n\rangle$ ($f(s)<f(t)$ if $x<t$) coincides with $(-1)^n\Omega(P,-n)$

So all I can think to do is induction on $n$. But I can't even get past the base case. So if $n=1$ and $|P|=1$ then I get a single term; $(-1)^{-1}(-1)=1$ which makes sense; there is only $1$ map to be found (namely the constant function to $\langle 1\rangle$. Now when I try to use the formula for $|P|>1$;

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=(-1)^{x}\Omega(P,x)\\
&=(-1)^x\sum_{s=1}^{|P|}(e_s){x\choose s}\\
&=(-1)^x\left(e_1x+\frac{e_2x(x-1)}2+\ldots+\frac{e_{|P|}x(x-1)\ldots(x-|P|+1)}{|P|!}\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

Then:
$f(-1)=(-1)^{-1}(-e_1+e_2-e_3+e_4...)=\sum_1^{|P|}(-1)^{s+1}e_s$.

This is clearly stupid, right? This sum needs to be zero always since we can't have a strict order-preserving map if the co-domain has a single element (unless the domain is a singlet as well, of course). Please tell me the stupid thing I'm doing/missing. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Ok there is a tiny logical error above. If P has the property that if $x \leq y$ then $x=y$(In other words; the Hasse Diagram has no edges) then there will indeed be a single map, so the sum should evaluate to 1, not 0. It still makes no sense that the answer depends on the parity of |P|.

EDIT: I foudn this paper [http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/7.pdf](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/7.pdf) That has the formula different. I suppose there is a misprint in my book. It should be;

$$\overline{\Omega(P:n)}=(-1)^{|P|}\Omega(P:-n)$$

Induction is a poor strategy anyway. I would have to know the answer to $\overline{\Omega({P;n}}$ ahead of time (in terms of $e_s$) and that has proven very difficult.

Comment: Here is the mistake with your base case: you forgot to include the $e_s$ values. It should be
$$
(-1)^1\Omega(P,-1)=-\sum_{s}e_s\binom{-1}{s}=e_1-e_2+e_3-e_4+\dots
$$
Then, for whatever reason, you have to show this sum evaluates to zero when $|P|>1$.

Comment: There is a keyword missing from the original post. $e_s$ counts surjective POSET maps.

Comment: @Muselive: It does work in the simplest test case: if $P=\langle k\rangle$, then $e_s=\binom{k-1}{s-1}$, and $$-\sum_{s=1}^ke_s\binom{-1}s=\sum_{s=1}^k(-1)^{s+1}\binom{k-1}{s-1}=0\,.$$